# Google Wallet Getting customer email address

Tags: android-pay

Google Wallet for Digital Goods - I'm implementing it.

There seems no way to get the customer's email address.

I'd like to get that - so that some info can be mailed to it etc.

p.s. this is in reference to the POST callback once a transaction
is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the customer's permission to use their email address. This should be done on your website where the digital goods transaction takes place.

At the simplest you can ask for the email address when the purchase happens and then associate the email address with the order id you receive in the postback.

Comment: How do I get the permission.

I'm calling the W4DG api javascript buy() function right now.

Comment: You need to do that yourself on your website, e.g. use an HTML input field and then store the email address in your customer database.

Comment: Isn't one of the major ideas behind W4DG to streamline the process.

If google has the email address why not pass it or have a checkbox user can sign off on.

Why make it more combursome (sp?)???

Comment: When the W4DG API javascript buy() function is called - isn't there a 'parameters' parameter - where additional info can be passed to the dialog.

Anyone have documentation on what values it can contain.

It seems a value option - would be to display a checkbox to the user to authorize email address to be passed to the merchant.

Other things like - compute taxes would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem.  It is even worse since we were using checkout API (that google decided to deprecate) and there you **could** get the buyer email from the postback HTTP call.

So having forced to move from checkout API to w4dg api, I have to deal with reduced functionality ...